# Laravel how to save belongstomany in store controller?

Tags: laravel

I can save my ticket inside a ticket table. But i also have a ticket_user table with inside a ticket_id and a user_id. So when the user press save it need to automaticlay pick also the ticket_id and the user_id inside the ticket_user table. I have a many to many table between Users and Ticket.

this is the error i get  `Call to a member function attach() on null`

User Models

```
public function ticket(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class, 'ticket_user');
}
```

Ticket models

```
public function users() {
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ticket_user');
}
```

Controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, array(
             'title'      => 'required',
             'ticket'     => 'required'
         ));

         $ticket = new Ticket;
         $ticket->title = $request->title;
         $ticket->ticket = $request->ticket;
         $ticket->save();

         $ticket->users()->attach($request->input('user_id'));

        return redirect()->route('users.tickets.index');
    }
```

Comment: Why You are not using Auth??

Comment: do you authenticate users?

Comment: Yes i have authenticate users

Comment: What isn't working with your code? Are you getting an error? You need to provide more details, what you expect to happen, what is happening, and any debugging details.

Comment: The problem is it saves on the ticket table but not on the ticket_user table

Comment: Hmm, your error is saying `$ticket->users()` is `null`, but that shouldn't be the case, since you've defined it as a relationship. Do a `dd($ticket, $ticket->users());` before the `attach()` code and see what's up.

Comment: can you share the migration code for the Pivot table?

Comment: are pivots columns are user_id and ticket_id ?

Comment: Yes they are user_id and ticket_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything in `users` function in **Ticket** class.

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'ticket_user');
}
```

Comment: Wauw i didn't notice it.